# Update Manager Error ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, updates, software-center, update-manager, lts

Red exclamation point in triangl up there is scareing me when i click on it this shows up:

> The update information is outdated.This
>   may be caused by network problems or by a 
>   repository that is no longer available. Please
>   update manually by clicking this and
>   then selecting 'check for updates' and check
>   if some of the listed repositories fail.

So I do that and once its done checking this comes up:

> Failed to download repository information
>
> Check your Internet connection.
>
> > W:Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
> >     , W:Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
> >     , W:Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
> >     , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I yook out one of the t's in HTTP because the 10rep thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa/?field.series_filter=karmic

This is the list of packages pmcenery offers. You should review them and make sure that these are packages that you need/want. If you don't you're better off removing them from your Software Sources (under Other Software tab) in Ubuntu Software Center.

If you do want these software packages, test out those ppa.launchpad.net links in your browser and sift through the directory till you find the folder that closely matches the folder Terminal is looking for and correct the difference in Software Sources. The problem is likely that the links are just broken and need to be updated.